# How to request Facebook publish_actions permission during login in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

To request facebook publish_actions permission during login in android I do

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setPublishPermissions(“publish_actions”);
loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
        FacebookOptInFragment.this.user = user;
        updateUI();
    }
});
```

That’s all I need to do and I am done. User will first login and then get prompted to grant publishing permission. How do I do the exact same thing in iOS?

Note that I just now downloaded the Facebook SDK, which means I have the latest and greatest (in case that is relevant).

Comment: You should never request publish_actions on login. You should only do it when you need it

Comment: @WizKid thanks for the advise :). It's actually the only thing I need for the entire app. So essentially that is what I am doing.

Comment: You are publishing something on the persons timeline directly when they login? That is a horrible thing to do

Comment: @WizKid, or login just before publish ; )

Answer (score 0):

Some [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions) first

> Requesting publishing permissions with publish_actions during login
>   creates a second step in the login UI. So you should request minimum
>   read permissions during login then request any additional or publish
>   permissions when someone actually needs them. To optimize your
>   permission requests, see Optimizing Permissions.

So If all you need is to authorize your iOS app and grant `publish_actions` permission and if you really want integrate with iOS Facebook account, you have to ask for reading permission before you ask for the publishing permission. See the `Request at Login portion` of the page link above for getting read permissions.

Then you can request additional permissions for `publish_actions` like

```
// Request publish_actions
[FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                      __block NSString *alertText;
                                      __block NSString *alertTitle;
                                      if (!error) {
                                        if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions 
                                             indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
                                          // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not publish
                                          alertTitle = @"Permission not granted";
                                          alertText = @"Your action will not be published to Facebook.";
                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                          message:alertText
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                                        } else {
                                          // Permission granted, publish the OG story
                                          [self publishStory];
                                        }

                                      } else {
                                        // There was an error, handle it
                                        // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                                      }
                                    }];
```

Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#optimizing) portion of the docs for permission management as well

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I already tried what you are suggesting and it does not work. See the following question, which I asked as a result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843758/how-do-i-login-with-facebook-in-my-ios-app

Comment: The link doesn't seem to exist ?

Comment: I found myself asking essentially the same question just because I couldn't get a complete answer. So I removed that one.

Comment: Where would you add this code? In the view did load?